# Visual Studio Attach To Process takes a -long- time to show up

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ide

Since about a month or 2, the Visual Studio 2015 *Attach to Process* dialog takes 1-2 minutes to show up on one of my machines. It used to take just a few seconds, it feels as if it is suddenly taking an enormous effort to retrieve the process list.

Needless to say, this is taking the swiftness out of my ad-hoc debugging sessions. Any tips to get it back into the previous working state, or insights into the underlying cause, would be much appreciated.

[image: For those who do not know what the Attach to Process dialog looks like :)]

Restarting the computer (e.g. after a Windows Update reboot) temporarily fixes the issue.

**Note**: The attaching itself works fine, and is as fast / slow as ever. Most related questions seem to be about symbol loading, but that bit is working nicely.

**Additional details**

- My computer has modest specs (16GB mem, fast SSD, i5-6600) for a dev machine.
- According to the task manager, it is not working particularly hard while retrieving the process list. Will inspect more in detail.
- As an experiment, I waited until things got slow again, and randomly started shooting down processes using Process explorer, reducing the number of processes from 261 to 209. Fast as ever now. Seems one of these processes is the culprit (or perhaps there is a bit flip in VS at > 256 processes :D), now I only have to wait for things to become slow and do further testing.

Comment: https://github.com/adamdriscoll/poshtools/issues/338

Comment: This is a long shot, but any chance your workstation is running any AppSense software?  Do you see any processes or services with AppSense in the description, or any processes called `AMAgent.exe`?

Comment: Does "show processes from all users" changes anything? What about the list you have in "select...". Anything funky? Have you tried to specify what you want exactly? I have: GPU - Software Emulator, Managed (CoreCLR), Managed (Native compilation), Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0), Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0), Native, Node.js Debugging, Script, T-SQL, Unity, WebKit, Workflow, Managed Compatibility Mode

Comment: Sorry that was the list on VS 2017, my list on VS 2015: GPU - Software Emulator, Managed (CoreCLR), Managed (Native compilation), Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0), Managed (v4.6, v4.5, v4.0), Native, PowerShell, Python, Script, T-SQL, Unity, WebKit, Workflow, Managed Compatibility Mode

Comment: @HansPassant Not using Poshtools, but the suggestion there to use process monitor for analysis might help. Thanks!

Comment: @Simon mourier: Thanks for the suggestions! I have the same list of code types, but that only affects the attaching process, which happens -after- the the problematic "retrieve processes" step and the dialog has been succesfully displayed. Show processes from all users does not seem to affect the speed.

Comment: Whats configuration of your system?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Do you have any specific suggestions? Hardware-related, you mean? I personally think some specific processes (or the sheer number) are to blame, but if you have specific suggestions I can test (mem bank scan, etc) I'm more than willing to try.

Comment: @Paul-Jan try deleting all your breakpoints

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved this in VS2017 15.5, (most likely) by uninstalling support for NodeJS and Python in VS.
I got the idea when reading about someone who solved it by uninstalling PowerShell tools, which I didn't have installed.

I used the connection type default, but noticed some new connection types in the drop-down, for example, Python and NodeJS.

I trimmed away some stuff from my VS installation that I don't really use at the moment, nodejs and python support and also Azure and Boost & Google test support. After that, it was fast and smooth again. It's a bit sad that the performance is affected by the unselected connection types as it seems, I hope it will get fixed soon.

Comment: I do agree with you, also uninstalled Python development from VS Installer and "Attach to process" window is now fast as it should be.

Comment: This is great - but *how* do you unstall the Python support ?

Comment: I have to agree with @HackerBaloo, I installed Python64 tools from VS Installer and also installed Python installer from internet. And then it started taking around 11 seconds to view list of processes. After uninstalling all python (from windows and VS), it now takes less than a second. Microsoft should find out the reason as this is reproducible. I will also try PROCMON and see why is that.

Comment: Great solution! I've had this problem for MONTHS and it's been driving me crazy. Never thought it could be python/node tools, it definitely was. Very fast now that I removed it. Luckily I dont actually need those tools.. Definitely seems to be a bug...

Comment: Well, a bit late, but on the question on how to remove the unwanted parts. Start Visual Studio Installer (in your start menu), select modify, and then I do it by selecting individual components.

Comment: THANK YOU! I had the same problem in VS 2019. Everytime i tried to attach to a process it took an awefull long time (2min) to update the running application. Uninstalling the Python support in VS speed up the process extremly, now it only takes one second.

Answer (score 4):

### Visual Studio 2015

In Visual Studio 2015 the attach process dialog doesn't open until all the processes are ready. This has been changed in more recent versions to open immediately and then progressively show the processes as they become ready.

Quoting a support response from the Visual Studio Team

> Visual Studio 2015 wouldn't open the dialog until the list of
>   processes was ready, but for 2017 we changed the dialog to open
>   immediately and show the processes list once it is ready.

Source: [Visual Studio Developer Community: Attach to process really slow](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/34728/attach-to-process-really-slow.html)

So I suspect that there may be something else related to the machine that is slowing down the processes.

### The machine

Now you say it's on one machine and with all things being equal with your Visual Studio usage, settings, project type, etc. Then it's likely an issue with your machine.

I've had similar difficulties with all my windows machines over the years. They start off fast and then end up painfully slow for developing. 
The fact the problem is rectified on reboot, indicates there's some issue, perhaps a memory leak? that's causing the pc to slow down.

What I would do to attempt to improve performance:

- Go through all the startup programs and disable most of them.
- Uninstall any third party security software. They take up a hideous amount of processing. Use the inbuilt Windows 10 security features.
- Ensure the pc is regularly defragmented and unused files are deleted.
- Check task manager for which processes are using up the CPU or memory (or disk). There may be things that can be done if you find the troublesome area.
- Reinstall Visual Studio and it's dependencies from scratch.
- Reinstall Windows and then reinstall VS.
- The pc may not be adequate for the job.  Upgrade or even better replace it.

I switched from Windows to Mac earlier this year, as I'd had enough of the bugs in Windows and the gradual decrease in performance. I forked out for a brilliant machine and haven't looked back.

The up and download speeds alone, on the same network as the Windows machine is 10 times faster. Everything about it is faster. The CPU on the Windows running on [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/au/) is actually faster. I can have Android studio stable, plus the beta open and run Visual Studio on Parallels, have chrome running and many other smaller apps and it will run faster.

I'll come back to you if this changes, but I honestly think it's a superior machine, OS, and hardware. This is coming from using State of the Art Windows machines. The best Windows machine was a gaming laptop, for performance. It too deteriorated until it just stopped working.

Comment: +1 for writing an answer this detailed and probably relevant to a lot of people. However, my Windows development experience is in tip-top shape aside from this little problem, and my PC definitely isn't slowing down, it's just that one action in particular that takes a lot of time.

Comment: I also do iOS development (on a MBP that costs as much as a bunch my windows development machines combined), and being hit hard by http://www.staingate.org/ makes me slightly less enthusiastic about that class of hardware :)

Comment: Did not mark this as "the answer" because it doesn't apply to my specific situation, but I've awarded the bounty because it's a high-quality answer. Thank you! Will add an answer of my own when I've identified the specific processes causing my problem (hopefully with details why), bit swarmed with work atm.

Answer (score 1):

See if Python installed as Visual Studio Workloads. If yes, then Uninstall Python Workload.
Its easy to uninstall workloads. Open Visual studio installer
[image]

[image]

Uncheck the checkbox for Python and click modify button. It will take a while. When setup
is finished. You are good to go.

[image]